# Save opened web page as a HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, save

I have an HTML page.
When I click a button, I'd like to trigger a Save HTML page kinda thing so that I'll be able to save the opened web page. I'd also like to know if this is possible using the jquery / javascript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML pages do not have access to the filesystem. This would be a security issue. The user needs to save the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

With IE, it's simple as IE implements document.execCommand:

```
document.execCommand("SaveAs", false, "Test.html");
```

MSDN has an clear [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of this.

If you're interested in having it work on other browsers, there doesn't seem to be any client-side programming that will invoke the Save dialogue box.

Using, server-side code, you can have the button retrieve the same page with the following change in the HTTP header sent with the response:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.ext
```

(where filename.ext is obviously the name of your file).

The first [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in the PHP documentation for the header() function shows how to invoke the download dialog for a PDF, and Microsoft has another [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) with an example for ASP.